# Xubuntu 13.04 Panel items alignment changed

Tags: xubuntu, xfce-panel

My friend did something on the while I was away and the alignment of the items in both panels changed.

The Applications Menu button and any opened programs are still left-aligned, but the User-name, Workspaces and all the other indicators are suddenly left-aligned too.

On the bottom panels it's also left aligned, instead of being centralized.

Answer (score 3):

I just figured it out by accident:

Add Separator between the items you want to be left-aligned and right-aligned,
on separator properties toggle "Expand" and select "Transparent".

On the bottom panel add 2 Separators (one on each side of the icon group), toggle both to "Expand" and select both to be "Transparent".